# Fastest way to process all rows and columns in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a method which pulls information from a MySQL table and passes it to a dataframe. Then I check all items in the DF, column by column, to see if they contain a prefix and if they do, to decrypt it. Any idea how to run this as fast as possible?

I can tell this is a very inefficient way to process but it's becoming an issue with large tables with over 400,000 rows. It has a second check since some data is decrypted twice, there may be a more elegant way to recursively do this I suppose...

```
for i in df.index:
        for c in df.columns:
            if type(df.loc[i, c]) == str:
                if "Crypt#" in df.loc[i, c]:
                    df.loc[i, c] = decrypt_data(df.loc[i, c])
                    if "Crypt#" in df.loc[i, c]:
                        df.loc[i, c] = decrypt_data(df.loc[i, c])
return df
```

Comment: Can you give us more information about your df, how it is and your desired output?

Comment: Hi Emanuele, the DF is a series of transactions in this case. Many different types of columns are encrypted but it is not consistent between tables, which is why we check to see if data in the column contains the encryption prefix. The output should be exactly the same, except columns which contain decrypted data are decrypted.

Comment: @atomey what is/are the datatypes of your various columns? Are the columns well-formed/structured (so that if there are any `str` in a column, the whole column is `str`)? Or in a given column/row, do you have a mix of different datatypes?

Comment: If the data is mixed, the first step should be to filter it by (some known markers?) so that it is well-formed/structured

Comment: Are you able to provide any details of the operation of the `decrypt_data` function? Or is that (so far as StackOverflow need be concerned) a "black box" function?

Comment: Are you able to generate a pseudo-example dataframe (or provide code to generate one)?

Comment: Does the string `"Crypt#"` always occur as the first 6 characters of a given (encrypted) item? The `in` check could be replaced by a `startswith` check, which should be (much?) faster if the strings are of any sizeable length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I understand the problem, you want to use `decrypt_data()` on the values of all cells of `df` if they are a `str` and have a prefix of `Crypt#`.

While I am not to sure this will offer a lot more performance, the simplest methods would include using `pd.applymap` or `np.vectorize` with `pd.apply`

```
# dummy DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1': np.random.choice(["Crypt#", "string", "int"], 10),
     'col2': np.random.choice(["Crypt#", "string", "int"], 10)}
)

def _decrypt(string):
    if string.startswith('Crypt#'):
        return decrypt_data(string)
    else:
        return string

# dummy decrypt_data func
def decrypt_data(string):
    return string+"decrypt"
```

Then you could use:

```
df.applymap(_decrypt)
```

or

```
df.apply(np.vectorize(_decrypt))
```

**Sample Output:**

```
            col1            col2
0  Crypt#decrypt         string
1         string  Crypt#decrypt
2  Crypt#decrypt            int
```

This assumes that all the values in the column are of the same type, as otherwise you would need to account for that.

In terms of performance, we could compare these functions to your original code snippet and see that there is some time savings. Also it should be noted [in the np.vectorize docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) it states that it is primarily for convenience and effectively a for loop so it isn't really doing this calculations in a vectorized way.
I can't think of a more preformant method in pandas because you can not easily vectorize your custom function.

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Your version made into a function
def original_func(df):
    for i in df.index:
        for c in df.columns:
            if type(df.loc[i, c]) == str:
                if "Crypt#" in df.loc[i, c]:
                    df.loc[i, c] = decrypt_data(df.loc[i, c])
    return df

def original(df):
    return original_func(df)
def applymap(df):
    return df.applymap(_decrypt)
def np_vectorize(df):
    return df.apply(np.vectorize(_decrypt))

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.choice(["Crypt#_string", "string2", "int"], n),
                                'col2': np.random.choice(["Crypt#_string", "string2", "int"], n)}),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: original(df),
        lambda df: applymap(df),
        lambda df: np_vectorize(df)],
    
    labels=['original', 'applymap', 'np_vectorize'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(1, 20)],
    equality_check=None,  
    xlabel='~N Groups'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks bkeesey, will give this a try soon. Very curious about trying it vectorized in particular, I would expect tat that to be more performant but perhaps not. I will let you know my results comparing all 3 methods. I suspect runtime will drift depending on what DF it applies too since encrypted data is different in size and frequency.

Comment: Hi bkeesey, sorry for the delay. I was able to use this successfully with the perfplot module. I'm not sure what numpy_decrypt is here but I simply ran it against your _decrypt after also adding a check for the string type first. I am using this with applymap successfully. I did run the perfplot on sample data and the graph printed was very similiar to yours.

Comment: Glad this works, this was a typo in my code snippet. It should be `_decrypt` instead of `numpy_decrypt`. Will edit the response.